# how to: put buttons on title Area with side menu activate codenameone?

Tags: button, command, codenameone

i need to build 2 buttons on title area with a sidemenu. so i built a side menu, works fine. but i don't know how to build a button in my title area.
i try this

```
command.putClientProperty("android:showAsAction", "withText)
```

but put the command in the sidemenu,not a titleArea.

i built this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQDLi.png

and i need build this buttons 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfVmk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an Android native option and the side menu is a portable UI.

To get a similar effect with the side menu use:

```
cmp.putClientProperty("TitleCommand", Boolean.TRUE);
```

See http://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-the-side-up-on-top